# TimerTask doesn't work with testng

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, testng

I want to implement TimerTask in TestNG but it is failed.
Have a look at my code

```
  public class Task extends TimerTask {

    static int i =0;
    @Override
    public void run() {

        System.out.println(++i +" : Hi");
        if(i==40){
           System.out.println("inside run method");
           cancel();
           System.exit(0);
        }
    }

  }
```

The upper class is my Task that I want to implement

```
  public class TestCount{
     private static final long DELAY = 0;
     private static final long PERIOD = 100;

    @Test
    public void test(){
       Timer timer = new Timer();
       timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Task(), DELAY, PERIOD);
    }
  }
```

Output:// 1 : Hi

The above code when I am running printing only time instead of 40 times. Help me....

Comment: 1. `TimerTask` has been superseded by `ScheduledExecutorService`; 2. why do you want to do that exactly? TestNG's `@Test` has a `timeout` parameter

Comment: Actually I want to build my own polling method. Here in my code I am trying to achieve this by TimerTask......Any alternative?

Answer (score 0):

I come up with the solution for this question. For those who don't want to use polling of fluentwait can use this class that I am posting. And I've achieved this without using THREAD or SLEEPER. This class will treat as POLLING alternative.

```
public class PollingClass {
private final long MAX_WAIT_IN_SECOND = 60;
private long MAX_TIME_COUNT_IN_MILLISECOND = System.currentTimeMillis()+MAX_WAIT_IN_SECOND*1000;
private long MIN_TIME_COUNT_IN_SECOND = 10;
private static int i = 0;

WebDriver driver;
WebElement element;

public PollingClass(WebDriver driver){
    this.driver = driver;
}

public WebElement getPolling(String path){

    try{
        while(System.currentTimeMillis() < MAX_TIME_COUNT_IN_MILLISECOND)
        {
            try{
                 element  = new WebDriverWait(driver, MIN_TIME_COUNT_IN_SECOND).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector(path)));

                 if(element.isDisplayed()){
                     System.out.println("element"+ ++i+" is displayed ");
                     break;
                 }  

            }catch(NoSuchElementException e){
//                  e.printStackTrace();
                continue;
            }
        }
    }catch(NoSuchElementException|TimeoutException e){
//          e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return element;
  }
}
```